# How to paginate array of key values using mongoosePaginate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I created Category Schema where there is Array of Products I want to paginate items of array not category it self, How can I fix this issue???

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');

const categorySchema = new Schema({
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
  items:[{
   
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
   
  }]

 
});
categorySchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
const Category = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
module.exports = Category;
```

if I do it like this it wont work it says "category.items.paginate is not a function"

```
let category = await Product.findOne({ category: mycategory })
let categoryItemsPagenateResult = category.items.paginate()
```

Answer (score 0):

for this situation you don't need to any plugin, just use `$slice` like this:

```
let skip = 0
let limit = 3;
let x = await Product.findOne({ category: mycategory }).select({ 'items': { '$slice': [skip,limit] } }).lean()
```

in `x.items` you have result